# How could an app know from which page it is being accessed?

Tags: facebook

Sorry for my English first,

Ok, for example my app is installed in two pages, but I need to change the content according to these two pages. So I need that app knew from which page has been accessed. Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sends a POST variable called "signed_request" to your iframe, you can read and encode it but the easiest way is to use the PHP SDK. It offers a function called "getSignedRequest": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getSignedRequest

The fields include a page object with the ID: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

If you don't want to use the PHP SDK, here is an example how to encode signed_request: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games